# Multiple Regression Assumptions

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation, assumptions, leverage, cooks-distance

This may seem like a basic question, but I'm verifying the assumptions for a multiple regression and have some trouble wrapping my head around homoscedasticity. I have a few questions listed below:

1) Are the assumptions of linearity and homoscedasticity related?

2) Is the assumption of normality also related to linearity and homoscedasticity? In other words, can you still have a linear relationship between variables even though the data is skewed? Can you still have the assumption of homoscedasticity even though the data is skewed?

3) When do cook's distance and leverage values come in handy?

4) If all variables should be normally distributed in a multiple regression, how would you transform data that includes a true 0. For example, number of minutes exercised per week (which is strongly skewed in the positive direction as most people report not exercising)

Comment: There is no requirement that variables be normally distributed. The distributional assumption is for model errors, not variables. Also, the normality assumption is arguably the least important among all assumptions. Normality is not needed for the OLS estimator to be unbiased, consistent and asymptotically normal.

Comment: Normality is often needed for the estimators to have good mean squared error, otherwise outliers can ruin the regression coefficient estimators.  Normality is needed if you want to estimate quantiles or exceedance probabilities.  That is why ordinal regression has many advantages over OLS; ordinal regression can estimates quantiles, probabilities, and the mean without nearly so strong distributional assumptions.

Comment: Your question is leaving out two additional assumptions: (1) no omitted variables, and (2) the outcome is distributed i.i.d (e.g. the dependent variable does not take a form like $y_{i} = f(y_{i<1})$).